# Having multiple custom check-in policies in VS 2015

Tags: tfs

I have been asked to create a second custom checkin policy for a second project on our TFS server. So both projects reside on the same TFS server in the same collection but are different projects under that collection. I created the second check-in policy just like the first. When I run the VSIX installer the new one installs. Once I run VS 2015 I can see both custom check-in policies under the TOOS/Extensions and Updates. However when I go to TEAM/Team Project Settings/Source Control/Check-in Policy the new one does not show when you click "Add". The existing one is there but not the new one.

Is there an issue with having two custom check-in policies?

Comment: Did you select the right  team project ? You said you have add it to different projects. Make sure you have choose the right team project for the new custom policy

Answer (score 0):

First please make sure you have selected the right team project. Since the check-in policy is based on team project- level.

Also remember to registering Custom Policy:

**You need to add an entry to the Windows registry so that your policy appears in the Add Check-in Policy dialog box.**

Here is an example of the .reg file that registers the policy.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
"Devart.ReviewAssistant.TeamFoundation"="c:\\Program Files\\Devart\\ReviewAssistant\\Devart.ReviewAssistant.TeamFoundation.dll"
```

*Note: that you must install the policy assembly on every computer that needs to have a reference the assembly.*

Make sure that you provide valid installation instructions for your policy as it will help fellow developers to install it. More detailed info please refer this blog: [Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy](http://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html)

Comment: In the past I have never had to do anything with the registry. However under The registry path you show does not exist for me. Under ...\VisualStudio I have a 10.0, 12,0, 14.0, 8.0, etc directories. Under 14.0 there is not TeamFoundation directory (or under any of the others). Now under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Micorosoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies I find what you are describing. There I have both my custom check-in policies yet only the one is showing in VS.

Comment: p.s. I am running VS Enterprise 2015 Update 2 on Windows 10

Comment: Another comment. These are normally installed via VSIX files not a .reg file. I have never had to use a .reg file or edit the Registry in any way.